# General questions about Android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk

I've been working for a month with android ndk, so I am quite a newbie. Currently I am trying to integrate some code into a big project and have multiple problems both with NDK and gstreamer. Questions are stupid but I would be very grateful if someone helped me:

1) After I build and compile a project, do I still need all of those Android.mk files? Or can I just add `.so` libraries using `System.loadlibrary("library")`?

2) After I build my `.so` files, do I still need to declare all `.a` files as build-shared libraries and link them to the `.so` which needs them?

3) When I add native android support, do I need to create separate `libsomename.so` or choose the existing?

Maybe someone could also link me to the good article about building?

Comment: In 1st question i have all so's and objects in armeabi and armeabi-v7

Comment: 3) you don't need to specify a new library name. But if you _add native support_, you cannot do 1) or 2)

Comment: So how am i supposed to debug my code? I have some code from other project which i need to build and use with the help of System.loadlibrary and i have mine code which i need to debug and get results from operations and only after i make sure i debug, delete mk file and leave it be with .so file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)No, if its already compiled all you need is the so and loadLibrary call.  However, if you want to update the library with your app its probably a good idea to keep them

2)No, once you have a .so file that's all you need

3)I'm not sure what you're asking there.

Comment: thank you for the first two questions. By third i mean that when i add native support for android project in order to debug. It askes me to input lib(somename).so for some cause. Do i need to input new name or just choose already existing.